# mongoose.find() - why nested array is returned as [Object]

Tags: node.js, mongoose

In the mongoose model for a member schema there is a nested array. When I use model.find() method to fetch all the documents within the collection, it returns the nested array as an Object. Therefore I am not able to use it in the angular front end.

Pls let me know where I am going wrong.

**mongoose model**

```
const memberSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  aptNumber: { type:String, required: true },
  wing: String,
  floor: { type:Number, required: true },
  sqFt: { type:Number, required: true },
  owners: [{
    title: String,
    fullName: String,
    role: String,
    mobile: String,
    email: String,
  }],
});
```

**Node Route**

```
router.get('/', authorize(), memberCtlr.getMembers)
```

**Node Controller**

```
exports.getMembers = (req, res, next) => {
  let fetchedDocs;
  // memberService.getMembers()
  Member.find()
    .then(documents => {
      fetchedDocs = documents;
      console.log('Member.find(): ', fetchedDocs)   // <<<<< see below the result of this
      return Member.countDocuments();
    })
    .then(count => {
      res.status(200).json({
        members: fetchedDocs,
        totalCount: count
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json({
        message: "Server Error in fetching Clients data!"
      });
    });
}
```

**Result of console.log**

```
  {
    _id: 5ff312bfe944f205b03b19b4,
    aptNumber: '102',
    floor: 1,
    sqFt: 700,
    owners: [ [Object] ],        <<<< WHY THIS is returned as Object
    __v: 0
  }
```

Comment: This seems to be just formatting issue; have you tried ```console.log(JSON.stringify(fetchedDocs));``` ?

Comment: I changed the code on controller as ```Member.find().lean().then(documents => {fetchedDocs = JSON.stringify(documents);``` With this I can see the owners array in the console.log. But this breaks the app in the front-end. Is there anything I need to do while receiving this data in Angular.

Comment: My suggestion was only about using `JSON.stringify` for logging purpose; you should return `fetchedDocs` as it is to the frontend (or in any case, not as a string)

Answer (score 0):

Add .lean() to your query.

Ex :

```
Member.find().lean()          // <<<< Add it here
    .then(documents => {
      fetchedDocs = documents;
      console.log('Member.find(): ', fetchedDocs)   // <<<<< see below the result of this
      return Member.countDocuments();
    })
    .then(count => {
      res.status(200).json({
        members: fetchedDocs,
        totalCount: count
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json({
        message: "Server Error in fetching Clients data!"
      });
    });
```

Comment: thanks. But the result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved. It was my mistake. In the Angular Material table, where this members array was used, I did not point to the right field within owners array. That's why I was seeing [Object Object] in the UI. And I thought it was because of the way the data was getting transmitted from the server.

Sorry, about this. It was my mistake.